# Pop from empty list

Tags: python, timer, timeit

I wanna calculate the time of 'pop'.
here is the code.

```
x=list(range(10000))
popz=timeit.Timer("x.pop(0)","from __main__ import x")
print (popz.timeit())
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

How can I get the time of pop from the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the [`timeit` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) runs a million times.  However, your list is only 10000 items long.  So when `timeit` runs, the first `10000` times will happily pop, but the `10001` iteration will fail.  You can set the number of times explicitly:

```
popz.timeit(n=10000)
```

but ... this is a really tricky timing situation since you want to time how long it takes to `.pop`, but the size of your list is constantly changing.  If you're looking for the asymptotic performance, you probably could verify that `.pop(0)` has asymptotic performance of O(N).  However concrete times are going to be hard to come by since you either have to time the amount of time it takes to create the list along with the `.pop`, *or* you're list is constantly changing while you're timing it.  Neither of these is ideal ... But I guess that's the problem with trying to time non-idempotent methods...

Answer (score 0):

Try like so

```
>>> import timeit
>>> x=list(range(10000))
>>> timeit.timeit("x.pop(0)","from __main__ import x", number=len(x))
0.01635134604293853
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try to use different between two variables(datetime) that you define before and after pop.

I'm not sure, but maybe its the way)
But there is an error, which is equal to time of the second variable assignment(after  "pop").

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now()
# ...wait a while...
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print(b-a)
```

Well, and I'm not sure about the accuracy of the timedelta in this case.

Comment: Thank you,maybe the accuracy of this case depends on many issues,such as workload of pc.I'm not sure either.